# ASP.NET Authentication in PhoneGap app is not possible?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cookies, cordova, cors

I have a phonegap app requesting data from an external url. Some of that data is protected by Authorization. I have implemented asp.net forms authentication on an asp.net webapi project. I have an authorize method and several data methods, where some require you to be authorized.

The authentication method

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("authenticate")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Authenticate(LoginCredentials credentials)
```

And the action requiring authentication

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public List<MediaItem> GetAllCatalogs() {
```

When running it all in local/test environment, it all works great. When i deploy the webapi and access it from my localhost, it breaks because of cross domain violation. Even the calls that did not require authentication. My first solution was to implement jsonp, which worked great for the calls not requiring authentication. I found out, that i needed to add withCredentials to the xhrFields, but it turned out that with jsonp, headers are not sent, since it's no longer a simple ajax request but instead a script load that doesn't include headers. The cookie returned from the Authenticate method would not get passed along with the call to GetAllCatalogs.

CORS to the rescue? I enabled CORS on the server by allowing * (EVERYBODY - yay!) it turns out that withCredentials are not allowed to use in conjunction with

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

When i swap the * with localhost, i can make it run on my local machine. That is great, but what is the hostname of a phonegap app? It turs out it is *nothing* just an *empty string* since phonegap does not rely on the http protocol with a domain to load its internal pages, it simply uses the file protocol (file://)

> Surely other people have run into this problem? Using phonegap to
>   access data on external urls, requiring authentication in cookie-form
>   is a common setup?

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, the browser in phonegap apps are pretty indifferent about the dangers when mixing Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * and withCredentials. Once you add everybody (*) in the xml config in your phonegap app, it won't  complain and let you make the x-domain calls.

The config is a little different on the different devices, but if you use phonegap build, this is the setting that will allow you to mix it:

```
<access origin="*" />
```